# An $ n × n $ matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2 = 0 $. Can the rank of $A$ be $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

An $ n × n $ matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2 = 0 $. Can the rank of $A$ be $n$?

My opinion is that $A^2 = 0 $ then $A$ is also $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: No, $A^2=0$ does not imply $A=0$, consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, $A^2=0$ does not necessarily imply that $A=0$.

Regarding your first question, if $A^2=0$ we have $0=\det(A^2)=(\det A)^2$. Since the determinant of $A$ vanishes, $A$ cannot have rank $n$ by definition. And actually the rank of $A$ must be $\leq \frac n2$ (see the comments again).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$A^2=0$ implies the *minimal polynomial* of $A$ is  a divisor of $X^2$.